# Кидает 404 ошибку, при переходе по @WebServlet("/FrontController")

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat, servlet

Написал сайтик, есть html код

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8"
    pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Set locale</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myStyle.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="container">
  <h1 class="ribbon"><strong class="ribbon-content">Set language</strong></h1>
  <form action="FrontController" method="get" class="selec">
   <input type="hidden" name="command" value="setLocale" />
   <p>
    <div class="select">
     <select name="locale" name="slct" id="slct">
        <option value="US">English</option>
        <option value="RU">Russian</option>
     </select>
    </div>
   </p>
   <input type="submit" class="ae" name="singinButton" value="OK" />
  </form>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

При нажатии кнопки должно переходить в контролер, но выкидывает 404. Сервер использую Tomcat 9, работаю на IDEA.
Вот код контроллера

```
package by.web.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import by.web.logic.command.AddHostel;
import by.web.logic.command.Command;
import by.web.logic.command.GoToPage;
import by.web.logic.command.Regist;
import by.web.logic.command.ReservRoom;
import by.web.logic.command.SetLocale;
import by.web.logic.connection.MultiThreadConnection;
import by.web.logic.role.*;
import by.web.logic.singin.*;

@WebServlet("/FrontController")
public class FrontController extends HttpServlet {...}
```

Deploy at the server startup поставил на папку с вьюшкой.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а где код? так же добавьте логи томката

Comment: @Виктор что есть логи? и кода очень много. проблема в том, что я просто где-то скорее всего не так указал. До моего контроллера вообще не доходит

Comment: логи это информация о том, что происходит. Вы выложили максимум информации, которая не дает ответа о том, что вы делаете. Добавьте логи, адрес который пишете в строку браузера и код сервелета. Так же можете запустить томкат в дебаге и посмотреть, что получится